# CFX will hijack \services URL, how to disable or config it?

Tags: jax-rs

See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-ServicelistingsandWADLqueries,
If you input URL like http://localhost:8080/store/books/services, CFX will hijack the URL and return some service description.

But in my case, the URL http://localhost:8080/store/books/services should be one of my webservice URL. How can I disable CFX's hijack?

Answer (score 0):

By carefully reading the CFX document http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-ServicelistingsandWADLqueries again,
I know that CFX has the ability to configure service list URL:

> Note that you can override the location at which listings are provided (in case you would like '/services' be available to your resources) using 'service-list path' CXFServlet parameter, example:
>
> > 'service-list-path' = '/listings'

That is a org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet parameter.

Comment: can we stop completely the service listing